# Building the MongoDB Docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker

Following this docker [example](https://docs.docker.com/examples/mongodb/) to build and run a mongo db image.
But not able to build the image.

```
sudo docker build --tag himanshuy/repo

Usage: docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build a new image from the source code at PATH

  --force-rm=false     Always remove intermediate containers, even after unsuccessful builds
  --no-cache=false     Do not use cache when building the image
  --pull=false         Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image
  -q, --quiet=false    Suppress the verbose output generated by the containers
  --rm=true            Remove intermediate containers after a successful build
  -t, --tag=""         Repository name (and optionally a tag) to
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the path to your Dockerfile (use `.` if you already are in that folder) and using `=` with `--tag` or without it if you use `-t`; so:
`sudo docker build -t himanshuy/repo .` or
`sudo docker build --tag=himanshuy/repo .`

Comment: Thanks, I did use `.` before but forgot `=` with `--tag` option.